# Should one disable the Windows firewall for the Monero Wallet GUI?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, nodes, firewall

I have read a [report on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5lwg5m/made_a_video_to_help_the_cryptocurrency_community/dbz7tgw/?) for [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/noN6FvC6U80) that some users apparently need to disable their Windows firewall in order to be able to use the Monero Wallet GUI. Is that really needed?

I'm asking because I have tested a fresh Windows 7 system in VirtualBox, and I didn't need to disable the Windows firewall for the GUI to connect to one of the [moneroworld.com nodes](https://moneroworld.com/#nodes).

[image]

Comment: Does anyone know what ports should be allowed for the outgoing firewall rules? I know default is all outgoing is allowed. But the system is only used for monerod so I just want to be specific. I already have inbound ports at 18089 etc. Would the outbound just be the same port but just under the external host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To connect to one of moneroworld nodes, one has to establish an **outgoing** connection. Default firewall policy is to allow outgoing connections and block incomming connections. So you don't need to tweak the firewall to connect to these remote nodes.

For your own full node, that would be the opposite. This SE explains [how to remotely access your own full node](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/15/how-can-i-access-my-full-node-remotely-from-another-location/).

Answer (score 1):

In order to get full wallet functionality, there is no need to allow incoming connections with the local OS firewall. In this mode, you will make 8 outbound connections and 0 inbound connections, be able to listen to all transactions and broadcast transactions to connected peers.

I've tested this and everything appears to be working fine.